# print "Düsseldorf" with Python

Tags: python, utf-8, character, encode

I am trying to use the string Düsseldorf. When I do that :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "Düsseldorf"
```

it prints strange characters. Could anyone help me please ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe the coding thing only works for 8-bit encodings... and Python still escapes byte codes in a certain range anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> print u"Düsseldorf"
Düsseldorf
```

["Unicode In Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: Since the OP most probably uses an editor with a different encoding than the shell, prefixing with a `u` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your editor is not set to produce UTF-8 output. Setting it to output UTF-8 should fix the problem.

Alternatively, use unicode escapes:

```
print u"D\u00FCsseldorf"
```

Note that [*string literals*](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in Python 2.x should be prefixed with a `u`(for unicode). Unprefixed literals(like `"Düsseldorf"`) generate **`str` objects which are byte arrays** (despite the name), not strings. Therefore, in Python 2.x with a correctly configured editor, you want:

```
print u"Düsseldorf"
```

In Python 3.x, the situation has been rectified by letting `str` objects represent, well, strings, and introducing the `bytes` type for byte arrays, as in `b'D\xc3\xbcsseldorf'`.

Comment: still it printed ü correctly on my machine without the u prefix.

Comment: @soulcheck Yes, on a correctly configured system (where UTF-8 is used both by the editor and the shell), both `print 'Düsseldorf'` and `print u'Düsseldorf'` will yield the expected result. Unicode escapes work even if the configuration is broken. Greetings from you-know-where ;)